# How to exec a create view with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sp-executesql

I am trying to execute a view every time to procedure run. 
what is the problem with my code? why it doesn't work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MTBFAlterView @PressType nvarchar(50), @TestName nvarchar(50), @PressName nvarchar(50), @Phase nvarchar(50)
AS
--Failure Report Table
DECLARE @ViewDROP nvarchar(MAX) = 'DROP VIEW [dbo].[UV_filteredLogins]'
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
 DECLARE @STMT AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
                                    Create VIEW [dbo].[UV_filteredLogins]
                                    as
                                    SELECT logins.[ID]
                                        ,[Test_ID]
                                        ,phase.Phase_Name
                                        ,press.PressName
                                        ,pressType.Type_Description as PressType
                                        ,[Operator]
                                        ,[LoginDate]
                                        ,[LogoutDate]
                                        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,LoginDate,LogoutDate) as TimeDiff
                                    FROM [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Logins] as logins join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Presses] as press on logins.Press_ID=press.ID 
                                    join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Phases] as phase on logins.Phase_ID=phase.ID 
                                    join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[PressTypes] as pressType on pressType.ID=press.PressType_ID
                                    join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Tests] as test on logins.Test_ID=test.ID
                                    where phase.Phase_Name= @Phase1 and press.PressName= @PressName1 and pressType.Type_Description=@PressType1 and [Test_ID]=TestName1 and logoutDate is not null
                                        and Operator in (SELECT au.Email
                                                        FROM [UsersAuthorization].[dbo].[RolesMembers] as RM join [UsersAuthorization].[dbo].[ApplicationUsers] as AU on RM.ApplicationUserID=au.ID
                                                        where rm.roleid=1)';
    SET @ParmDefinition=N'@PressType1 nvarchar(50), @TestName1 nvarchar(50), @PressName1 nvarchar(50), @Phase1 nvarchar(50) OUTPUT'; 
    --EXEC sp_executesql @ViewDROP
   EXEC sp_executesql @STMT, @ParmDefinition, @PressType1 = @PressType, @TestName1=@TestName, @PressName1=@PressName, @Phase1=@Phase OUTPUT;



   exec dbo.MTBFAlterView @PressType='HP Indigo 10000', @TestName='Go Green', @PressName='MR-193', @Phase='Test'
```

my result is:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.

Comment: Edit your code i think you have missing @ in view :

Comment: Why you need to do so? What are you trying to do really? Seems like dropping a view and created again everytime isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Sami hi i didn't execute the delete after all, i am trying to create\alter a view with parameters that i will get from a user.

Comment: you must the pass value not variable (@PressName1) in create query

Comment: View's can't have variables in their definition. Are you wanting those variables to be converted to literal values in the VIEW's definition?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0846f837-9cda-4c60-9819-055f3c2aae79/create-view-using-spexecutesql?forum=sqlgetstarted

Comment: @Larnu I don't want the variables to be in the view i want their value to connect with the string, you think is possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the parameters you're passing to be literatl values in your `VIEW`'s definition, then this is the way you want to build it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MTBFAlterView @PressType nvarchar(50), @TestName nvarchar(50), @PressName nvarchar(50), @Phase nvarchar(50)
AS BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = 'UV_filteredLogins')
        DROP VIEW UV_filteredLogins;

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UV_filteredLogins]
AS
    SELECT logins.[ID],
           [Test_ID],
           phase.Phase_Name,
           press.PressName,
           pressType.Type_Description AS PressType,
           [Operator],
           [LoginDate],
           [LogoutDate],
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LoginDate, LogoutDate) AS TimeDiff
    FROM [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Logins] logins
         JOIN [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Presses] press ON logins.Press_ID = press.ID
         JOIN [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Phases] phase ON logins.Phase_ID = phase.ID
         JOIN [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[PressTypes] pressType ON pressType.ID = press.PressType_ID
         JOIN [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Tests] test ON logins.Test_ID = test.ID
    WHERE phase.Phase_Name = ' + QUOTENAME(@Phase,N'''') + N'
      AND press.PressName = ' + QUOTENAME(@PressName,N'''') + N'
      AND pressType.Type_Description = ' + QUOTENAME(@PressType,N'''') + N'
      AND [Test_ID] = TestName1
      AND logoutDate IS NOT NULL
      AND Operator IN (SELECT AU.Email
                       FROM [UsersAuthorization].[dbo].[RolesMembers] RM
                            JOIN [UsersAuthorization].[dbo].[ApplicationUsers] AU ON RM.ApplicationUserID = AU.ID
                       WHERE RM.roleid = 1);';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
END
GO
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` here. That keeps your dynamic SQL safe, by quoting the values appropriately when generating the values. So, for example, a value like "don't" would be parsed as `'don''t'`. This avoids Injection in your SP, which is really important when using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Views don't take parameters. If you had wanted to pass parameters at the point in time at which the view is used, you would define a [table-valued user defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017#FunctionTypes) instead.

However, here it looks like you're trying to set the parameters *separately* from where the view is used. Here, the best option may be some form of "parameter table" for the view, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE UV_filteredLogins_parms (
    Lock char(1) not null,
    constraint CK_UV_filteredLogins_Locked CHECK (Lock = 'X'),
    constraint PK_UV_filteredLogins PRIMARY KEY (Lock),
    PressType nvarchar(50),
    TestName nvarchar(50),
    PressName nvarchar(50),
    Phase nvarchar(50)
)
```

Now, the above table can either contain 0 rows or 1 row. I suggest that you just insert one row and now make your stored procedure issue an `UPDATE` against it instead.

Now, inside the view, you can simply join to this table and then compare these column values against the columns from the other tables<sup>1</sup>. You don't need to be dropping and re-creating it whenever the parameter values change.

I have no idea why `@Phase` was being marked as an `OUTPUT`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Either `CROSS JOIN` and continue to do the actual comparisons in the `WHERE` or an `INNER JOIN` and move some/all of the comparisons into it's `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want this SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MTBFAlterView @PressType nvarchar(50), @TestName nvarchar(50) 
, @PressName nvarchar(50), @Phase nvarchar(50)

AS
--Failure Report Table
begin
 DECLARE @ViewDROP nvarchar(MAX) = N'DROP VIEW [dbo].[UV_filteredLogins]' -- 'N' has been added
 DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
 DECLARE @STMT AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
  Create VIEW [dbo].[UV_filteredLogins]
  as
  SELECT logins.[ID]
   , [Test_ID]
   , phase.Phase_Name
   , press.PressName
   , pressType.Type_Description as PressType
   , [Operator]
   , [LoginDate]
   , [LogoutDate]
   , DATEDIFF(MINUTE,LoginDate,LogoutDate) as TimeDiff
  FROM [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Logins]        as logins 
  join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Presses]       as press on logins.Press_ID=press.ID 
  join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Phases]        as phase on logins.Phase_ID=phase.ID 
  join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[PressTypes]    as pressType on pressType.ID=press.PressType_ID
  join [TDM_Analysis].[dbo].[Tests]         as test on logins.Test_ID=test.ID
  where phase.Phase_Name= '''+@Phase +''' and press.PressName= '''+ @PressName +''' 
  and pressType.Type_Description= '''+@PressType +
  /*Parameter's values are applied in WHERE condition*/
  ''' and [Test_ID]=TestName1 and logoutDate is not null
  and Operator in (
   SELECT au.Email
   FROM [UsersAuthorization].[dbo].[RolesMembers] as RM 
   join [UsersAuthorization].[dbo].[ApplicationUsers] as AU 
   on RM.ApplicationUserID=au.ID
   where rm.roleid=1
  )';


  EXEC sp_executesql @STMT              -- View will be created.
  select * from UV_filteredLogins       -- Call it.
  --EXEC sp_executesql @ViewDROP        -- Drop query of view.
end

exec dbo.MTBFAlterView 'HP Indigo 10000', 'Go Green'
, 'MR-193','Test'
-- If you call this, then view is created and followed by 'SELECT'
```

Comment: Please consider injection when writing dynamic SQL. This is wide open to it.

Comment: @Larnu.. I don't have knowledge about injection. so let me study about the injection.

Comment: I certainly recommend reading up about Injection; making your (dynamic) SQL safe is an invaluable skill.